# Would like to ban my application for Tablets

Tags: android, google-play, tablet

I have uploaded my application in android market. But some tablet users keep getting application crash message, bcz of some technical issue. I would like to ban my application for tablet users. How to do that. Do i need to change anything in manifest file or in my market account? Please help me.

Comment: Not really answering your question...but maybe you can simply fix the crashes? Do you have some stacktraces of the Exception/s? If you don't own a tablet and you need someone to test something for you let me know. :)

Comment: I don't think so that its problem with my code :), its working fine with other devices, its making problem only with tablet.

Answer (score 2):

It seems that the best solution is to restrict screen sizes. [Follow this link.](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html)

Answer (score 0):

Are you using "supports-screens" tag. Problem likely is not in your code but the Manifest file.

Answer (score 0):

You can also block out the devices that has this problems on your application profile. But there are quite a lot of them to block.

Answer (score 0):

Use the support screens tag in your manifest.

```
<supports-screens android:xlargeScreens="false" />
```